# questions on Vectorize of R

Tags: r

I have a question regarding the following R code segment

```
n <- 20
theta <- 5
x <- runif(n)
y <- x * theta + rnorm(n)
empirical.risk <- function(b) { 
    mean((y-b*x)^2) 
}
true.risk <- function(b) {
    1 + (theta - b)^2 * (0.5^2 + 1 / 12) 
}
curve(Vectorize(empirical.risk)(x), from = 0, to = 2 * theta,
      xlab = "regression slope", ylab = "MSE risk")
curve(true.risk, add = TRUE, col = "grey")
```

This code segment makes use of the `Vectorize` but I do not quite understand how it works. Especially, in `curve(true.risk, add = TRUE, col = "grey")`  even no parameters are passed to `true.risk`

Comment: Can you add a short description of what you learned from the documentation of these functions, and discuss how the documentation was not clear? Otherwise, we're simply going to be repeating the docs back at you.

Answer (score 0):

So first, the `curve(...)` function works by forming a vector of length `n` (default n=101) of values between `from` and `to` (0 and 10 in your example). Then it passes that vector to the function defined in the first argument and plots the returned vector. So the first argument to `curve(...)` has to be "vectorized"; in other words it has to take a vector as an argument and return a vector of the same length.

Your function, `empirical.risk(...)` is not vectorized: if you pass it a scalar, you get what you would expect, but if you pass it a vector (e.g., multiple values of b), you get back a scalar. The reason is actually quite subtle and has to do with the use of `(y-b*x)`. If you pass a vector, R tries to form the product of the vector `b` and the vector `x` to create a new vector, which it then subtracts from the vector `y`. Then it takes the mean of that vector and returns a single value. What you want is a vector that is the result of running `empirical.risk(...)` on all the values of `b` in succession. This is what `Vectorize` does.

Another way to think about it is that `Vectorize(...)` is equivalent to wrapping your function with `sapply(...)`

```
f <- Vectorize(empirical.risk)
f(1:5)
# [1] 5.663989 3.660942 2.279632 1.520057 1.382219

sapply(1:5,empirical.risk)
# [1] 5.663989 3.660942 2.279632 1.520057 1.382219
```

Regarding the second part of your question, why the last line of code works: when `add=T`, `curve(...)` gets it's defaults from the existing plot. So, since you defined the vector `x` in that plot (using `from` and `to` and the default `n`), the second call to `curve(...)` uses that.